# collider around a word (GUI text)

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I'm making a simlpe word bazed game, and for that I'd like to have a collider around the words I'm displaying (I use GUItext for that).

I tried using a box collider, but I can't seem to find a good way to automaticly set size of the collider to match size of the word.

Code I've tried so far:

```
void setCollider()
{
    BoxCollider boxCollider = (BoxCollider) gameObject.AddComponent (typeof (BoxCollider));
    boxCollider.isTrigger = true;
    boxX = 0.1f * (guiText.text.Length - 1);
    boxCollider.size = new Vector3(boxX, boxY, 1);
}
```

This function is called from the *start()* function. It doesn't give consistent results.

Comment: If you have problem with code you should show that as well.

Comment: have you tried using something like renderer.bounds?

Comment: @normower No, I don't see how to use it.  


I've tried using `Rect box = this.guiText.GetScreenRect ();` and then getting width and height of the box, but it produced way to big  colliders.